# using glide with iocipher

Tags: java, android, android-glide, java-io, virtual-disk

I am using glide in order to set images in my GridView, and I am using a library named IOcipher which provides a virtual encrypted disk, so I use `info.guardianproject.iocipher.File` instead of `java.io.file` . But glide can't load images, and it has a error saying :

> E/Glide: class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
>   to load resource

is there any way I could load images? I tried many different ways :(
`file.getPath()` returns `/data/user/0/com.example.zeinab.amndoorbin/app_vfs/myfiles.db/1502685968291.jpg`

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(file.getPath()) // Uri of the picture
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Your file path contains two slashes app_vfs//myfiles which is wrong it should be only one slash /.

Comment: @I solve it but again the same problem :(

Comment: @sara did you find a solution?

Comment: @arjun sorry for the long delay :(The only thing  I  understood is that  glide is not compatible with Iocipher.

Comment: @sara how did u use IOCipher? i cant even start simple project when i add iocipherstandalone